# Add multiple products to cart in php

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I need some help, how to add multiple products? will I add a code or change some? help please. thank u for response.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tut");
    $test= $values['item_name'];
    $test3 = $values["item_quantity"];
    $test2= $values["product_price"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO orders (Quantity,PriceDetails,OrderTotal) VALUES ('$test3','$test','$total')";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}
```

Comment: you have to iterate x times (x is the number of products you want to add) through the code that stands in the if statement, but before doing that you have to have a collection of products to add in your db, for this purpose you could use a multidimensional array

Comment: sir can u give me some examples on how to do that? sorry, because im just only a begginner, im begging u sir :(

Comment: the management of the cart has to be done with sessions

Comment: this means that before adding your order to the database, the products are saved server-side, you have to have a structure that has inside the products the user want

Comment: can u re-edit my code sir? please i need to finish this because tomorrow is my final defense, if I failed im broke :(

Comment: @uzumakicarlo when someone answers your question and you were so desperate for an answer you should accept their answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

Just try to inspire yourself with the code below.
Also try to safe your data with simple add-on:

```
$test = mysql_real_escape_string($values['item_name']);
```

You may come alright:

```
function db_action($data = array()) {
    switch ($data['action']) {
        case 'insert':
            $keys = array(); $values = array();

            foreach ($data['data'] as $key => $value) {
                $keys[$key] = $key;
                $values[$key] = "'".$value."'";
            }

            $keys = implode(', ', $keys);
            $values = implode(', ', $values);
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$data['table']." (".$keys.") VALUES (".$values.")");
            break;
        case 'update':
            mysql_query("UPDATE ".$data['table']." SET ".$values." WHERE ".$key." = ".$id);
            break;
        case 'delete':
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM ".$data['table']." WHERE ".$key." = ".$id);
            break;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: @uzumakicarlo, You are welcome. Then if this Answer please you, Please mark it as a correct answer for you and everyone to know. I hope you will make it.